# How to start an app from a bash script without opening/showing terminal window?

Tags: bash, scripts, 22.04

I want to run a bash script that starts an app without opening up a terminal window and then the app. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.

I have two problems.

First, The below script when run by itself it launches a terminal window and then qbittorrent.  Is there a way to not have the terminal window open?

Second, my vpn app (torguard) allows me to run a bash script when the vpn is connected. The below script does not work at all.  I do know that the script is running because if I run it by itself it works but opens a terminal windows also.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/qbittorrent
```

I have tried the following command in the script.  These don't launch anything.

```
/usr/bin/qbittorrent &
/usr/bin/qbittorrent &>/dev/null &
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your first script as written will not launch a terminal window. If a terminal is loaded, then either it is the qbittorrent program itself that opens a terminal emulator, or you are loading it using a .desktop file with `Terminal`  set to `True` . Provide detail on how you run that script.

Comment: Thank you for responding. My bash script now contains /usr/bin/qbittorrent &>/dev/null &.  The script is running from Torguard but ignores starting qbittorrent.. Tjhere are no errors in the loggin. When the script is run normally from outside Torguard it launches qbittorrent fine.  Ideas?

Comment: So please update the question. You told the script opened a terminal window, which clearly cannot be correct if you run the script either from the terminal or from a run prompt. Note that you now show running a separate command '>/dev/null': that will do nothing. Revise your question and make it specific and precise, e.g. when you write `The below script when run by` also mention *how* you run it (from terminal emulator? From run prompt?)

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question well you want to run a script with out the need to open the terminal right

To start an app from a bash script without opening a terminal window, you can use the & symbol at the end of the command. This tells the shell to run the command in the background.

here is a example

```bash
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/qbittorrent &
```

try this for the Vpn

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Wait for the VPN to connect
while ! ping -c 1 google.com; do
  sleep 1
done

# Start qBittorrent in the background
/usr/bin/qbittorrent &
```